# help finding a webtoon

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I'm helping a friend find a webtoon she read 3 years ago.
What she remembers is the main charater is a red haired boy with magical powers, but is keeping it a secret. A black haired boy who plays baseball finds out and keeps it a secret too.
The red haired boy also has a grandmother who who has magical powers too.